# how to query a one to many relationship in sqlalchemy without duplicates

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to query the posts and i want to get all the comments too

this is my model for the parent and child

**parent**

```
class Post(Base):
__tablename__ = "posts"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    published = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, default=text("NOW()"))
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    comments = relationship("Comment", backref="post")
```

**Child**

```
class Comment(Base):
__tablename__ = "comments"
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
     email = Column(String, nullable=True)
     name = Column(String, nullable=True)
     content = Column(String, nullable=False)      commented_at=Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),nullable=False,server_default=text("NOW()"))
     post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("posts.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
```

and im querying with join like **this**:

```
posts = db.query(models.Post, models.User, models.Comment).outerjoin(
    models.User).order_by(models.Post.owner_id).outerjoin(models.Comment).order_by(models.Comment.post_id).all()
```

this is the result but here it is giving me 2 times the post with the id 1 for each comments if the post had 5 comments it will give me 5 times de same post

```
{
        "Post": {
          "title": "string",
          "id": 1,
          "published": false,
          "owner_id": 1,
          "content": "string",
          "created_at": "2022-01-30T21:49:17.851582+02:00"
        },
        "User": {
          "username": "TheBossmanLab",
          "created_at": "2022-01-30T21:47:20.416480+02:00",
          "email": "super_user@gmail.com",
          "is_super_user": true,
          "id": 1,
          "password": "$2b$12$UEt0mzRp2qiLweJXwTztFuyWGcAfx6h5UFRE3avf3bt82wLzPZxTC",
          "is_admin": true
        },
        "Comment": {
          "commented_at": "2022-05-15T21:59:29.830714+02:00",
          "id": 1,
          "name": "666",
          "email": "666@gmail.com",
          "content": "granda post",
          "post_id": 1
        }
},
{
            "Post": {
              "title": "string",
              "id": 1,
              "published": false,
              "owner_id": 1,
              "content": "string",
              "created_at": "2022-01-30T21:49:17.851582+02:00"
            },
            "User": {
              "username": "TheBossmanLab",
              "created_at": "2022-01-30T21:47:20.416480+02:00",
              "email": "super_user@gmail.com",
              "is_super_user": true,
              "id": 1,
              "password": "$2b$12$UEt0mzRp2qiLweJXwTztFuyWGcAfx6h5UFRE3avf3bt82wLzPZxTC",
              "is_admin": true
            },
            "Comment": {
              "commented_at": "2022-05-16T11:45:33.501141+02:00",
              "id": 2,
              "name": "666",
              "email": "666@gmail.com",
              "content": "nqowrbvowrb",
              "post_id": 1
            }
},
```

what i want as a result:

```
{
            "Post": {
              "title": "string",
              "id": 1,
              "published": false,
              "owner_id": 1,
              "content": "string",
              "created_at": "2022-01-30T21:49:17.851582+02:00"
            },
            "User": {
              "username": "TheBossmanLab",
              "created_at": "2022-01-30T21:47:20.416480+02:00",
              "email": "super_user@gmail.com",
              "is_super_user": true,
              "id": 1,
              "password": "$2b$12$UEt0mzRp2qiLweJXwTztFuyWGcAfx6h5UFRE3avf3bt82wLzPZxTC",
              "is_admin": true
            },
            "Comments": [{
              "commented_at": "2022-05-15T21:59:29.830714+02:00",
              "id": 1,
              "name": "666",
              "email": "666@gmail.com",
              "content": "granda post",
              "post_id": 1}, 
              {"commented_at": "2022-05-16T11:45:33.501141+02:00",
                      "id": 2,
                      "name": "666",
                      "email": "666@gmail.com",
                      "content": "nqowrbvowrb",
                      "post_id": 1
                    }]
        },
```

i think i over explained the situation but really im deseperate i think im blocked i cant think of any solution to this pleasse help me.

Comment: Any reason for not using the existing `comments` relationship on the `Post` model and loading that through a join, instead of fetching Post/User/Comments separately?

Comment: That's what I did but it gives me 2 posts with the id 1 one for each comment but i want to get 1 post with id 1 with a list of comments

Comment: That's not what your query does, it gives you a list that's the combinations of all matching comments/posts/users.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding based on your question is that you want to query a list of posts which includes the information about the `User` and the `Comment`s associated with the post.

If that is the case then instead of loading all three entities you could choose to create a relationship between the `Post` and `User` (referenced by the `owner_id`)

Since you're question does not offer details about whether a `Post` can exist without a `User` you can use the following query to fetch posts associated to a user.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload, contains_eager

posts: Post = (
    db.query(Post)      
      .join(Post.user, User.id == Post.owner_id)
      .options(contains_eager(Post.user))
      .options(joinedload(Post.comments))
      .order_by(Post.id.desc())
      .all()
    )
```

If an association is created between `Post` and `User` then `User.id == Post.owner_id` becomes redundant and can be skipped.

The comments are simply eager loaded based on the relationship.
The join is only needed if there is no explicit relationships defined.

Both `contains_eager` and `joinedload` can be a bit tricky if you're new to sqlalchemy.

The TLDR version is that you'd use `contains_eager` where you've already instructed SqlAlchemy to load data with a join. In our case that would be the `join(Post.user, User.id == Post.owner_id)` while `joinedload` simply uses the defined relationships to eager load the association.

1. [contains_eager](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager)
2. [joinedload](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload)

### Update

I see that you've mentioned the `nullable` constraint on the foreign_key for the `Posts` to `User` relationship. In that case this should be more than adequate.

```py
posts: Post = (
    db.query(Post)            
      .options(
         joinedload(Post.user),
         joinedload(Post.comments),
       )
      .order_by(Post.id.desc())
      .all()
    )
```